# Double counting by overlapping buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm conducting research on the effect of park installations on homicides. To do this, I make buffers of the parks and then use the cut function to select the homicides that occurred within those buffers.

My problem is that due to the size of the buffers they overlap (very close parks) generating that some homicides are within more than one of the buffers, to avoid double counting problems I want to assign the homicide only to the closest park, somehow to do it from QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you need.
Leaving aside SQL-based queries, two out-of-the-box tools could be:

- `Processing` menu -> `Tools`->`Distance to nearest hub (points)`
- `Processing` menu -> `Tools`->`Join attributes by nearest`

In both tools you can select the "installations" layer as reference and the "homicides" layer as target (or vice-versa) anr yield an output layer which contains the data/points from the reference layer and the reference (key) to the target layer.

Answer (score 5):

On the point layer `homicides`, run this expression with Field Calculator. Change distance of `300`, name of layer `park` and attribute field name `park_id` according to your needs:

```
overlay_nearest(
    'parks',
    park_id,
    max_distance:=300
)[0]
```

*Black labels created with the above expression; parks = green polygons, green lines = 300 m buffer around parks:*
[image]

Comment: This is a Clean, Concise, and Clever method :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really easy and useful this way.

Answer (score 4):

If you still have your source layer for the buffers by hand you can use this little Python script:

```py
### Settings:
unbufferedlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Unbuffered')[0]
pointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]
countfieldname = 'cnt'
maxdist = 10000 # set this equal to your buffersize

### no changes needed ###
unbuffered_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(unbufferedlayer.getFeatures(), flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)
resultdict = {}

for point in pointlayer.getFeatures():
    nearestneighbors = unbuffered_idx.nearestNeighbor(point.geometry(), neighbors = 1, maxDistance = maxdist)
    if nearestneighbors[0] not in resultdict:
        resultdict[nearestneighbors[0]] = 0
    resultdict[nearestneighbors[0]] += 1

with edit(unbufferedlayer):
    unbufferedlayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(countfieldname, QVariant.Int)])
    unbufferedlayer.updateFields()
    for feat in unbufferedlayer.getFeatures():
        if feat.id() in resultdict:
            feat[countfieldname] = resultdict[feat.id()]
        else:
            feat[countfieldname] = 0
        unbufferedlayer.updateFeature(feat)
```